# how to use batch file script zip assign files

Tags: batch-file

i have a folder structure in this pattern. I've just shown two sub directories and 2 files in each but generally I have n number of subdirectories at a single level and single level of files (but can be n number of files)under them.

```
Directory master
subDirectory x:
  file1.aa
  file2.bb
Directory y:
  file.bb
  file.aa
```

I need to create a windows script, a batch file to run from the master directory and give me two zip files `x.zip` and `y.zip` containing their the `aa` extension  files.

I know the script

```
for /d %%a in (*) do (ECHO zip -r -p "%%~na.zip" ".\%%a\*")
```

is to zip all the files, but i don't know how to just zip only with `aa` extension.

Comment: how about `(*.aa)` instead of `(*)`?

Comment: it's can't be run and i think i ask wrong, what i want to solve is zip file without extension aa.

Comment: for /d %%a in (*) do (  
  %zipPro% a -tzip "%%~na.zip" ".\%%a\\*\\*a" 
) the command can to zip with extension a files, but if i want to zip without extension a files, how should i change the script?

Comment: `for /d %%a in (*) do (ECHO zip -r -p "%%~na.zip" ".\%%~a\*.aa")`

Comment: yes, but if i want without extension aa, how should i to change the script. eg: in the fold has extension bb, extension cc and so on other files.

Comment: Then you could make copies of the files with file names without "aa" and zip those.

Comment: yes, i tried success, thanks for the method.